# Get revisions of a spreadsheet with gdata Python api

Tags: python, google-docs-api

I'm trying to get the revisions of a spreadsheet using the key, but it just returns "Invalid resource id".

```
from gdata.alt import appengine
from gdata.spreadsheet import service
from gdata.docs.client import DocsClient

self.ss_svc = service.SpreadsheetsService()
# ... login code ...
gd_client = DocsClient(self.ss_svc.GetClientLoginToken())
rev_uri = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full/%s/revisions" % spreadsheet_key

# i also tried:
rev_uri = "spreadsheet%" + spreadsheet_key
rev_feed = gd_client.get(rev_uri)
```

Nothing works. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is a bit confusing because you refer to `self` but this doesn't appear to be part of a class definition. Also, you say you "also tried" `gd_client.get(rev_uri)` but I don't see what you tried before that -- no other method of `gd_client` is called in the above code. And finally, you're using the `get` method, which performs a http GET form request, which I don't *think* is what you want mean to do.

Seems like what you want is [`get_revisions`](http://gdata-python-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pydocs/gdata.docs.client.html#DocsClient-get_revisions). I'm just guessing -- let me know if this is mistaken.

Comment: I already tried that. How can I get the resource id though? using the ccc key always says "Invalid resource id". Sorry if the post wasn't completely clear. This code is heavily pared down to make it as readable as possible.

Comment: Wow! Got it working. Sometimes you just need someone to tell you to try what you already tried, again. Thanks alot! I'll post the answer.

Comment: Yes I was just going to say that I think the `%` character should be a `:` -- that must have been the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured this out, but not sure if the solution is completely right. Either way, it works.

```
class SpreadsheetLoader(object):  
  def __init__(self,config):
    from gdata.alt import appengine
    from gdata.spreadsheet import service
    from gdata.docs.client import DocsClient

    self.ss_svc = service.SpreadsheetsService()

    appengine.run_on_appengine(self.ss_svc, store_tokens=False, single_user_mode=True)
    self.ss_svc.email = config.dev_email
    self.ss_svc.password = config.dev_pwd
    self.ss_svc.source = 'Spreadsheet Loader'
    self.ss_svc.ProgrammaticLogin()

    feed = self.ss_svc.GetSpreadsheetsFeed(config.spreadsheet_key)

    # token = self.ss_svc.GetClientLoginToken()
    # gd_client = DocsClient(token)
    # token passing doesn't seem to work. It errors out with "str doesn't have some_method" :(
    # so I just login again... whatever.
    gd_client.client_login(config.dev_email, config.dev_pwd, "My App")

    resource_id = "spreadsheet:" + config.spreadsheet_key
    rev_feed = gd_client.get_revisions(resource_id)
```